# Projeto API com muitas camadas

Tags: c#, api, design-pattern

Estou estudando sobre API.

Vi um padrão de projeto com essa camadas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Achei desnecessário as camadas AppServices e DomainServices. Para mim o ideal seria criar apenas uma camada de Services onde estaria toda minha regra de negocio OU na própria API estar contido a regra.

Gostaria de saber se estou errado, ou se o padrão de projeto da imagem é a melhor forma...

Comment: A resposta correta é que um projeto nao representa obrigatoriamente uma camada. Com base nesta afirmacao ninguem sabera dar uma resposta sem saber exatamente o codigo de cada projeto

Comment: Olá! Sabe dizer qual a intenção original de cada projeto criado?

Comment: @Dherik onde eu estava estudando, ficou meio confuso, pois todos os projetos faziam a mesma coisa. Apenas chamava outro projeto que chamava outro... por isso achei desnecessário

Answer (score 1):

Uma coisa que aprendi é que não existe um padrão de projeto que sirva para todos os casos. Indo um pouco aos extremos, se a sua aplicação deve apenas somar dois números, criar 5 projetos(Services, Infra, App, etc) diferentes é simplesmente exagero.

Essas divisões que nós criamos tem um e apenas um objetivo: organizar código. Pense nelas como gavetas. Esse pedaço de código que eu estou escrevendo agora merece o trabalho de arranjar outra gaveta?

A quantidade de divisões da sua aplicação deve ser proporcional  a complexidade dos domínios abordados.

Answer (score 1):

Concordo com o Genos, tudo ira depender da complexidade do seu projeto e do seu cenário.

O ideal é termos o menor numero possível de camadas, ou seja, somente as necessárias.

Separando em camadas, além de organizarmos o código estamos tornando aquele grupo em algo reutilizável em outro contexto, imagine que um dia você deseje implementar uma nova aplicacao para esse mesmo dominio da API. Com o dominio em um projeto a parte podemos simplesmente referencia-lo para a nova aplicacao.

Para ajudar a pensar em como separamos segue um [link](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) do Uncle Bob que escreveu o livro Clean Code muite interessante tambem.

Answer (score 1):

Vou dar uma sugestão de como podem ter pensado nesta organização, que me parece pensado como uma aplicação SOA:

- **Api**: utilizado para os serviços Rest.
- **AppServices**: utilizado pelos serviços Rest. Contém as regras de negócio.
- **DomainServices**: o nome está estranho, mas pode ser o local dos repositórios (DAOs).
- **Domain**: classes de domínio (entidades) do sistema, que mapeiam o banco de dados.
- **Data**: este eu realmente não imagino o que possa ser.

Mas para saber mesmo, só olhando o código.

Answer (score 1):

Se você **ainda** não é capaz de entender um padrão de camadas proposto, simplesmente não use-o. Não adianta simplesmente colocar N camadas se você não entende o porque cada uma existe.

Existe um conceito [KISS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_It_Simple) (Keep it simple, stupid), não estou chamando ninguém de estúpido, é o conceito. Traduzindo é mantenha isso simples. Assista essa [palestra](https://www.infoq.com/br/presentations/a-arquitetura-peculiar-do-stack-overflow) de uma colaboradora do StackOverlflow, é em português. Você irá ver a simplicidade por detrás desse site. A simplicidade muitas vezes atende.

Na maioria dos casos o simples padrão MVC que vem por padrão numa solução ASP.NET irá atender. No seu caso de uma API, não vai ter as Views, mas não teria necessidade de sair criando camadas a não ser que seja extremamente necessário, e se você não consegue identificar se é necessário, então não faça.

Foque em entregar a funcionalidade ao cliente de forma segura e bem feita, pelo menos seguindo os principios básico da orientação à objetos como de separação de responsabilidade e o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120931/o-dry-%C3%A9-para-evitar-redund%C3%A2ncias-certo).

Pegue essa padrão de camadas, e tente desenvolver algo para testes, para que você possa aprender e entender, mas não faça algo que será vendido ou colocado em produção com algo que você não domine.